# Ajax request gets 0 length response when running java through cgi

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, cgi

This is how it does work:

```
<div id="result">Result will be printed here</div>

<form method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/execute.cgi">
  <input type="text" name="user" /> <br/>
  <input type="password" name="password" /> <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

execute.cgi:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
java -version
```

This will show output of "java -version" in a new page
So far everything works as expected.

However if I do the request with ajax:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/cgi-bin/execute.cgi',
      type: $(this).attr('method'),
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log('response length:' + response.length);
        $('#result').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Response will have body size of 0 and a status code of 200
It seems like 'java -version' is ignored or just not waited for it to print its output.
I rather think it is the latter case because if i switch to something lighter like 'ls -la' then it works like a charm.

So any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Add error block for your ajax request `error:function (errMsg){..}`. this will give you some hint on whats the error

Comment: Sadly there are no errors